# HAISU: Nought and Crosses

Tags: mazes, grid-deduction

HAISU is a portmanteau of three Japanese words - 'hairu', to enter, 'su', number, and 'hausu', an English borrow word meaning house, of course.
Together, we get a meaning of 'enter number house', which I have roughly translated to English as 'Room Count'.

The rules are simple - draw a path from the O to the X, passing through every cell in the grid exactly once. The grid is divided into several rooms. When your path passes over a cell with the big number N, it must be the Nth time you have entered the room. If a room has a small number m in the top left corner, you must enter that room a total of m times. An example Haisu puzzle and its unique solution are shown below.

[image]

[image]

Hopefully this example puzzle clarifies the rules. Your real challenge is this!

[image]

Note from TGE: This is slightly easier than my original Haisu puzzle, I think. It's also a lot prettier. Hope you enjoy :)
Another note: Had to fix the bottom right corner! Sorry to everyone who has already attempted the puzzle. Most of your progress should be unaffected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following solution satisfies all conditions:

> [image]

Step by step:

There are very few possibilities to get 7 crossings in the plus(+) tile, which leads to the following start.

> [image]

Because the 5 has to be crossed immediately before the 6 and they can not loop there is only one possible path.

> [image]

The blue line can not happen because it would make the path through the 4 impossible. This (together with the knowledge that there are only 3 crossings for the ring) leads to a nearly solved middle part.

> [image]

If the blue line would be valid, it would cause a loop, therefore the cell left to it has only one path left. That path can not form a loop, which leads to another path segment.

> [image]

Filling in missing paths where there is only one solution.

> [image]

We know the direction of the path that comes through the 5 and 6 at the bottom. When it crosses the top left plus(+) tile, it can either be the 5th, 6th and 7th crossing or the 1st, 2nd and 3rd. The latter leads to another loop which leaves us with only one possible path.

> [image]

To satisfy the 2 in the bottom right plus(+) tile there is only one path left.

> [image]

Comment: Congrats! This is the unique solution. I'll checkmark it when a little bit of an outline of how you got to the solution goes up :)

Comment: @TheGreatEscaper Let me know if I should expand on some steps.

Comment: I think it's enough to give a general idea of the solve path. Well done!