# Oriental House: An original grid-deduction challenge

Tags: no-computers, mazes, grid-deduction

A different approach to an [old concept of mine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49281/haisu-nought-and-crosses), Oriental House is a new grid-deduction puzzle based once again off exits and entries.

The rules are as follows: Draw a path from S to F, passing through every square exactly once.
The areas defined by bolded lines are 'rooms'. You may pass through rooms more than once. When the path passes over an arrow, the path segment inside that room over that arrow must either have entered or exited in that direction. Below are some examples of what is and isn't allowed, to make this rule a bit clearer.

[image]

These blue paths above are all fine paths since they all either exit or enter in the direction indicated by the arrow.

[image]

These red ones are bad because they don't exit or enter in the direction of the arrow. The first one is bad because moving in that direction during the path isn't enough - you MUST exit or enter in that direction.
The last one is bad, even though the room does get entered upwards - an arrow clue must apply to the entrance and exits of the **path segment it lies on**, not all entrances of the room in general.

Also, note that the path can pass over multiple arrows on a single entry. If both arrows are of the same orientation, then the restriction is the same as a single arrow.

Your real challenge is below.

[image]

Comment: Is a line allowed to pass through more than one arrow on the same box entry?

Comment: Yup! I'll edit that in, sorry.

Comment: In a few rooms(like the one containing the corners), there is no arrow shown. Does that mean, we can enter and exit through any direction?

Comment: If i do not touch the arrows can i enter or exit from any direction?

Comment: @Sid yup! No arrow means no restrictions at all.

Comment: @FrancescoRoggia yup! But keep in mind that you must pass over every square at some point, so you will have to pass over all the arrows at some point. Of course, if a path segment doesn't pass over any arrows, there are no restrictions on it.

Comment: @TheGreatEscaper So, the two arrows in a single room (up and down) mean, we can only use up or down to enter or leave room. Nothing else right? Or does it mean, any of those plus other direction?

Comment: @Techidiot no. If the room is passed through multiple times, then there are multiple entries and exits, not all of which need to be up or down. Consider the first or third blue example - there are no restrictions on how the rest of the room plays out. To further clarify, using NESW notation, if a room contains two arrows, N and S: Entering N, collecting the N arrow, leaving in any direction, entering again in any direction, collecting the S arrow, leaving South, would be legal. (Along with variants of the above)

Comment: @TheGreatEscaper One last question, if I have collected an arrow in a room say N. Now, if I want to re-enter and exit the room, do I need to use N again for enter or exit?

Comment: Is the solution unique?

Comment: @ZizyArcher yes. It's usually a given that grid-deduction puzzles should have a unique solution.

Comment: @Techidiot no. Arrows apply only to a single time you spend in the room, the time that you collect that arrow.

Comment: Is computer use allowed, or should it be solved manually?

Comment: @WeckarE. Manually. That's usually a given for grid-logic puzzles. Hand-made for a hand-solve, that's the way these should be :)

Comment: There's only 54 questions under the tag. I doubt that "Givens" have been established :)

Comment: @WeckarE. PSE is not the hometown of grid-deduction puzzles! :P http://www.nikoli.com/en/puzzles/ Is probably the most famous. The whole point of grid-deduction puzzles like sudoku, slitherlink, masyu, fillomino, is that they are puzzles that can be solved on paper with a pen/pencil, which immediately discounts electronic help.

Comment: Eh, don't assume people know the 'culture' of a puzzle, or even that certain puzzles fall into the same 'culture'.

Comment: @WeckarE. Apologies, it wasn't my intention to alienate solvers at all. I'll add the no-computers tag now :)

Comment: @WeckarE. I don't want to alienate anybody either, but this has nothing to do with cultural interpretation, it's right there in the [definition](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/grid-deduction/info).  If the final state of the grid cannot be deduced logically, then it is not a grid deduction puzzle.

Comment: @paramesis Computers happen to often be better at logic than humans :P

Comment: @WeckarE.My comment was mostly addressing the uniqueness "given". See [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1691/does-writing-computer-code-and-letting-a-machine-solve-a-puzzle-really-count-as) and [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5837/should-a-step-by-step-solution-be-a-requirement-for-some-genres-of-puzzles) for relevant debates about manual vs computer solving specific to this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chess notation as I am hopeless for drawings. Bottom left is A1, top right is I9. > for a single step, >> for multiple in a line. -- for other direction as << doesn't work.

Final solution:

> START>B7>B6>>D6>>D9>>A5>>C5>>C3>B3>B4>A4>>A1>B1>B2>C2>C1>D1>>D3>E3>>E1>>I1>>I4>>G4>G5>F5>F6>>H6>H5>I5>>I9>>E9>E8>>H8>H7>>E7>>E5>D5>D4>E4>F4>>F2>>H2>H3>FINISH

And in picture:

> [image: Solution]

Steps:

> H8 arrow cannot be used with exit of the room. Exiting at H8 would violate one of the G9 or I7 arrows, exiting at H7 would violate I7 arrow, exiting at H6 I6 arrow and exiting at F7 F6 one. So, H8 arrow defines room entrance direction.

.

> Likewise, G9>F9>E9>E8>F8 segment is needed to make F9 arrow work.

.

> Now the only path to make both segments + top right corner work is H6>H5>I5>>I9>>E9>E8>>H8>H7. Which means that by line continuation and arrows, you get G4>G5>F5>F6>>H6...>H7>>E7>>E5.

.

> Now how to get back to start point here? Well, the observation is that you cannot really pick F4 arrow and enter on left. So you must exit on left. So, we need to not block the exit, so we would get E4>F4>>F2>>H2>H3>FINISH. Remember this ..>>E5 part? From E5 we need to go D5 - we have an arrow. Then either D4>E4, or C5>C4>D4>E4. We shall figure out this later.
>  This means to get to G4, you would have to go G4--I4--I1--E1.

.

> So, we now need to go E1--E3 (note we are going in other direction, arrows are reversed then). By E4 line continuation, E3-D3. We cannot enter this small room just yet and need to go D3--D1-C1.

.

> One obvious part is D8>D9>C9. The less obvious part is picking up the D6 arrow. Using it to give exit direction cannot work together with the D9 arrow - you would get stuck. So, it is entry direction, meaning the path goes C7>B7>B6>>D6>>D9>>A9>>A5>B5.

.

> Now, to pick the C4 arrow and A4 ones, only B5>C5>>C3>B3>B4>A4 works. Now you simply need to go down, A4>>A1>B1>B2>C2>C1, where you now meet the other end.

Comment: Nicely solved! I'll give this the green tick, would it be possible for you to make some diagrams?